# Disable Hibernate caching in standalone GORM

Tags: hibernate, groovy, grails-orm

I have an application that runs the `GORM` standalone (i.e. without `Grails`). It all works fine, but it's using `GORM3` and I would like to port it to `GORM5`.

In a `Spock` specification I initialize the `GORM` to connect to the `DB` and I pass some custom properties, the most important one being **hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache**

In `GORM3` it is something like this:

```
    def init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer(ClassLoader.systemClassLoader, "my.pkg")
    def prop = new Properties()
    prop.setProperty('hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache', 'false')
    init.setConfiguration(prop)
    init.configureForDataSource(dataSource)
```

In GORM5 the type of AbstractDatastoreInitializer.configuration is not Properties but PropertyResolver.

I tried something like this:

```
def entities = getEntities()
def props = ['hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache': 'false']
def init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer(props, entities)
init.configureForDataSource(dataSource)
```

but that property is not picked up and hibernate complains that the second level cache is disabled but no factory is provided.

I tried in many other ways with no luck. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the GORM, it will be fixed in 5.0.5
https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/698